# Strange text color when using a custom NSTableRowView within a NSVisualEffectView

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I am using a custom NSTableRowView within a NSVisualEffectView. I implemented custom lighlight style in CustomTableRowView like this:

```
class CustomTableRowView: NSTableRowView {

    override func drawSelection(in dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        if (self.selectionHighlightStyle != NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyle.none) {
            if self.isEmphasized {
                NSColor(calibratedRed: 26.0/255.0, green: 154.0/255.0, blue: 252.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).setStroke()
            } else {
                NSColor(calibratedWhite: 0.82, alpha: 1.0).setStroke()
            }

            let selectionPath = NSBezierPath(rect: dirtyRect)
            selectionPath.lineWidth = 3.0
            selectionPath.stroke()
        }
    }

    override var interiorBackgroundStyle: NSBackgroundStyle {
        return NSBackgroundStyle.light
    }
}
```

But the text color in the selected row becomes strange, and the font becomes bold automatically. See picture below:

[image]

I have also put the sample code on [github](https://github.com/treblam/NsBoxPlay/tree/master/NsBoxPlay). What's wrong with my implementation? How to make the text color and font weight of the selected row the same as the rows which are not selected?

Comment: Really? If I run the code with xcode, only the last column of the selected row's color is changed, but if I swipe the tableview to make some rows to scroll below the toolbar, then the whole selected row's color is changed and text became bold.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the main issue stems from the Visual Effect View's Core Animation Layer. While it may not be the entire reason for the glitchy behavior deselecting the option for nested views helped:

[image: glitchy visual effect view]

In addition there are some other possible areas that can be adjusted (eg. `tableCellView`):

```
tableCellView.textField?.stringValue = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
tableCellView.textField?.font = NSFont(name: "Menlo", size: 11)
tableCellView.textField?.textColor = NSColor(white: 0.01, alpha: 0.75)
tableCellView.appearance = NSAppearance(named: NSAppearanceNameAqua)
...
```

It not clear to me why the text in the view seems to get bold and somewhat over-aliased, although I believe some of it is a result of Visual Effect View related bugs (see below)...

---

Incidentally, it seems that Xcode itself is affected by a similar behavior; in the Xcode Project Navigator after using a Visual Effect View sometimes the selected item turns white, which doesn't seem normal at all. My conclusion is that this is a bug (apparently related to the Visual Effect View).

[image]

Removing the Visual Effect View resolves the issue with the text, but not a real solution as you should be able to use it. Bugs and glitchy behavior should always be reported to Apple.

Comment: I seems it's not this reason, I have removed the font manager in the sample code on github, and the text still has a strange color and bold font, I suspect  this is because the textfield has a vibrancy effect, but do not know how to remove it.

Comment: Yes, I see that now — just by resizing the window the selection changes. Strange behavior indeed... I almost want to say this is a bug, because now when I select items in the Project Navigator the text turns white.

Comment: The text in Project Navigator turns white is OK, because there is a blue background below it normally, but sometimes I noticed the blue background is not there, and white text becomes hard to read, maybe this is a bug in XCode. But it's unrelated to my problem, right?

Comment: It's definitely the Visual Effect View causing the buggy behavior; I removed it and put the table into a Custom View and the text no longer has the issue.

Comment: I have searched on internet for a lot of time, and tried everything I could do, but not found any solution to this problem except to remove the Visual Effect View.

Comment: What are you using the Visual Effect View for exactly?

Comment: I want to use the behind window blending of NSVisualEffectView, so my app's background can blend with whatever is below it, to make my app more beautiful.

Comment: Yes I understand completely! I know that what you are wanting to do has to be possible, because I've seen other apps which don't suffer from the behavior you are experiencing. I'll try some other things and if anything comes to light I'll post back here asap.

Comment: Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of Vibrancy issues. Your `NSTextFields` are trying to be vibrant but the `NSTableRowView` is blocking this.

To solve it, and disable vibrancy, set the `textColor` of these text fields to anything other than `labelColor` or `secondaryLabelColor`.

So for instance, set it to `labelColor` in Interface Builder and then change the opacity by 1%.